# ETClient (401) Unauthorized with SDK C#

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, fuel-sdk, c#

I am using Visual Studio 2017, and install SFMC.FuelSDK by using Nuget.

I use this:

```
        NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
        parameters.Add("clientId", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        parameters.Add("clientSecret", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        ETClient myclient = new ETClient(parameters);
```

and get (401) Unauthorized. I get clientId and clientSecret from App Center. I tested my clientId and clientSecret with URL (https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken), and they are valid.

Does anyone know what I did wrong or what should I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please add the following line and try again:

parameters.Add("authEndPoint", "https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken?legacy=1");

Comment: Is there a document showing about this parameter?