# the remote server returned an error (401) unauthorized SalesForce

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce1-app, fuel-sdk, .net

I just wrote the code in [ETClient (401) Unauthorized with SDK C#](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197773/etclient-401-unauthorized-with-sdk-c#new-answer?newreg=f0f8b7d9e6d046308ea1d8b38d3c4e61) but the error remains. What should I do? I am using .NET 2015 and the FuelSDK
Thank you

Comment: Did you add the end points as parameters?

Comment: Yes I did. In fact I have tried with: https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken?legacy=1, https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token, https://auth-qa.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken?legacy=1 and no one is working!! Thank you again

Comment: Try https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken